# Given a joint density function, I want to calculate CEF and best linear predictor

Tags: regression, self-study, econometrics, joint-distribution, conditional-expectation

(This is problem from Bruce Hansen's Econometric Lecture notes (2.16). But there's no solution there and I have no one to ask because I am not a student.)

The joint density function is given as $(3/2)(x^2+y^2)$ on the support $[0,1]$ ($x,y$ both). I want to calculate best linear predictor for equation $y=a+bx+e$
and conditional mean function $m(x)=E(y|x)$. Here's what I've tried:

1. Computing best linear predictor

   $\newcommand{\cov}{{\rm Cov}}\newcommand{\var}{{\rm Var}}\newcommand{\ahat}{{\hat a}}\newcommand{\bhat}{{\hat b}} \bhat=\cov(x,y)/\var(x)$
   $\cov(x,y)$ is integration of $f(x,y)(x-E(x))(y-E(y))dxdy$, $x$ and $y=0$ to $1$
   $\var(x)$ is integration of $f(x)(x-E(x))dx$, $x=0$ to $1$
   $\ahat=E(y)-\bhat E(x)$

   (I calculated $E(x)$ ($E(y)$ respectively) by integration of  $x[f(x,y)dy]dx$, $x$ and $y=0$ to $1$)
2. Computing conditional mean function:

   Integration of $y[f(x,y)/f(x)]dy$ $y=0$ to $1$
   I have the best linear predictor as $\ahat+\bhat x=(45/146)+(5/73)x$ and conditional mean function $m(x)=(1/2)+[1/(12x^2+4)]$

However, I am not sure that I have reached to correct answer. My first doubt is that computation is too messy and second is that BLP has positive slope on $[0,1]$ and CEF has negative slope on $[0,1]$.

The following is a picture of CEF and BLP, based on my calculation.

[image: green : BLP, red : CEF]

Comment: Please write out your abbreviations: in particular, what does "CEF" refer to?

Comment: @whuber CEF = Conditional Expectation Function

Comment: @whuber-oh, i forgot to write it down. It's CEF : Conditional Expectation Function, BLP : Best Linear Predictor.

Comment: @Alecos Presumably that would be the same as the "conditional mean function."  Although "BLP" is fairly well known, "CEF" seems to be used only within a relatively narrow community (presumably econometricians).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more step-by-step approach could be:

The joint *distribution* function is

$$F(x,y) = \frac 32\int_0^y \int_0^x (s^2 + t^2)dsdt = \frac 32\int_0^y \left[\int_0^x s^2 ds+\int_0^x t^2ds\right]dt$$

Continue the simple integration to obtain

$$F(x,y) = \frac 12 x^3y + \frac 12 xy^3$$

That's the mother of everything.

Set each variable equal to the upper bound of the support to obtain the marginal distribution function of the other. Then differentiate to get the marginal densities (they should be structurally the same since the variables enter the joint distribution symmetrically). Calculate mean ($5/8$) and variance (they will be the same for both variables). Calculate covariance, and you can get your Best Linear Predictor.

As for the Conditional Expectation (or mean) Function, it can indeed be easily calculated from

$$E(Y\mid X) = \int_0^1 y\frac {f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}dy$$

and after a clever simplification one gets the result that the OP provides in the question.

This appears to be an exercise to show how the linear formulation of co-movement and the resulting predictor may differ from the actual relationship.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got density of x, f(x)=(3/2)x^2+(1/2). Is this wrong?

Comment: @HavingSomeQuestions It is correct. Keep going.

Comment: Don't getting the same result means for best linear predictor or conditional mean function? or both? I derive conditional mean function again but still getting the same result. (6x^2+3)/(12x^2+4).

Comment: @HavingSomeQuestions   What you write in the comment above is correct. But it is not the same with the CEF you have written in your original post.

Comment: Ah, I just wrote 6x^2+3 as (6x^2+2)+1. Then it becomes like the one in original post. I did it to separate constant term.

Comment: I found that i was wrong in calculating covariance. In original post I integrated f(x,y)(x-E(x))^2(y-E(y))^2 dx dy. Now i calculate covariance using formula cov=E(xy)-E(x)E(y)=integral f(x,y)xy dx dy -(5/8)^2=-(1/64). So BLP becomes (55/73)-(15/73)x. I think this is an reasonable answer! As you mentioned, I agree that this problem was made to show that linear predictor cannot excatly capture CEF movement. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HavingSomeQuestions Look again at the CEF you wrote in the original post. it cannot possibly be equivalent to what you wrote in the comment because in the original post there is no $x$ in the numerator.

Comment: @HavingSomeQuestions ...and if you found this answer useful, please check the green mark so that the thread does not stay in the "unanswered" queue of the site.

Comment: Yes I will check green mark. I am really thankful.  However, I think original post CEF is right... I think i was unclear, what i meant was that (6x^2+3)/(12x^2+4)=[(6x^2+2)+1]/(12x^2+4)=[(6x^2+2)/(12x^2+4)] + 1/(12x^2+4)=(1/2)+1/(12x^2+4). Thank you:)

Comment: Sorry..but where is green mark??? I cannot find it

Comment: @HavingSomeQuestions This simplification is correct - I corrected the parentheses to the original post. The green mark is the grey "check" sign to the left of my answer - it will turn green once you click it.